# What is the best approach to do a end-to-end test using selenium webdriver and junit5?

Tags: spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, junit5

Since selenium can't do rest call testing and since I found a lot of different interpretations of an integration test, I am having trouble understanding what is the correct approach to test my spring boot api using selenium and junit5.

For an example, if I were to have a button in my frontend that when clicked sends a rest call to the server how should I test the validity of the response? Initial idea was to make two calls, one using  selenium, one using MockMvc and compare the responses, though I can't seem to find a way to get the webdriver response. Or do I have to check instead for some changes on the frontend, also if I do that approach is it still an end-to-end test?

Also, considering I am not going to implement every single layer of abstraction (meaning the controller, service and repository) is MockMvc test approach enough for the test to qualify as an integration test or is it still a unit test?

Any explanation or code example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium and MockMvc are two totally different kinds of test.

Selenium is used for End-to-End test. You want to test your software from the perspective of a real human user. Therefore I would suggest that you check for changes in your UI because your real users also would not care for Rest-Responses.

`MockMvc` on the other hand *can* be used to test only the Web-Layer of your Spring application or the complete Application with all of its layers. Both are Integration Test but with a different scope of what is tested.
Here I would suggest you to make use of Springs Test Slices. If you annotate your Test with `@WebMvcTest` a Spring Context is loaded but it only contains the components needed to test your Web-Layer (Controller, RestController, ControllerAdvice, JsonComponents, etc)
For more information have a look at springs own tutorial on [Testing the Web layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).